# Are there database standards in Symfony and Doctrine?

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, standards

Symfony uses a set of coding standards to set out for us how to program and what style we should use. My question is short and simple. I would like to know if symfony (together with doctrine ORM) has a similiar set of standards when it comes to building and structuring my database.

For example:

- Should I use Camel Case?
- Should my table name be user or users
- Do I use capitals?
- What charset is recommanded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you do not need to care about database naming as Doctrine will do everything for you.

You should use [Doctrine `cli` commands](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#doctrine-console) to generate your database schema based on your entities, or even better use [Doctrine Migrations](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations) to maintain changes.

> Should I use Camel Case?

For entity class names, I'd recommend sticking with PSR, so yes, use CamelCase.

Symfony by default uses underscore naming strategy, so entity `CamelCase` will be generated as table `camel_case` (if not manually overriden).

You can [set another naming strategy](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/namingstrategy.html), but the default underscore strategy is a fine choice.

> Should my table name be user or users

`user` is a ANSI SQL reserved word, so I recommend using `users`. Or, if you prefer having entities in singular, try `person` instead.

> Do I use capitals?

Again, Doctrine naming strategy will solve this for you. Moreover, eg postresql converts all table names and such identifiers to lowercase, so using capitals explicitly can cause problems.

> What charset is recommanded?

Use UTF-8 (or more specifically utf8mb4 if needed). There are few reasons to use any other.